# Is localStorage access a heavy operation

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

A function in my application requires access of an array element.
I can either generate a random index every time this function is called or store the previous visited index into localStorage and then get this value and initialize index to 1+previous_index

I need to persist the index data for the case when user visits my application again.

So, now I have to choose between one. Either use **Math.random()** or use **localStorage**.

Which option will be more faster.

**PS :** even though this will have a very less impact on performance. But The main question here is **Are localStorage access heavy operations**

Comment: how about cookies ?

Comment: @shyammakwana.me — Terrible idea. They have limited size and are sent in every HTTP request. Cookies should be avoided unless you need to send the data to the server on every request.

Comment: I am not much familiar with JS. But I think using cookies is not a good option. I mean localStorage came to replace cookies

Comment: if localStorage was *heavy* it probably would have an asynchronous API (like the crypto API) - but it doesn't :p That's my opinion

Comment: @JaromandaX you seem right. but still, these are stored locally in filesystem. so they have to be slow. right?

Comment: @Quentin storing an index is not that heavy, right. As OP's concernd about heaviness then just reading index is not that costlier, Unless and until there are loops and/or bulk data to process. so LS or SS is not heavy.

Comment: @SwayamRaina  Google recommends that avoid use of IndexedDB, WebSQL and application cache. but not local storage and session storage.

Comment: @shyammakwana.me operation will be heavy if we are reading data from file system. It is not about processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it a heavy operation I'm inclined to say no..

Is it going to be slower then `Math.random()`? I would say it depends on your code.. (as in what else are you doing)

I made jsperf [here](https://jsperf.com/math-random-vs-localstorage/1)

```
var a = []

var key = Math.random()
a[key] =  'test'
```

vs

```
var a = []

var key = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('key')) || 0
localStorage.setItem('key', key+1)
a[key] =  'test'
```

the `Math.random()` is way faster but I don't keep any keys.. keys are floats and in my example you cannot use `a.length` because of the floats it returns 0 all the time!

Comment: the function will only give the index of the array last used if i use localStorage. But i dont need to think of last value used if i use random function.

Comment: true, but then again how random is random and how high is the probability for collisions an how bad would it be.. If I wanted a similar solution for this I would use uuid (or guid or whatever you want to name it) as a key. It's commonly used and depending on the implementation it's more reliable... but that is maybe a bit off topic :-)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your Question "Are local-storage access heavy operations" is **NO**
But compared to a local function, it is slower.
You can run the test given here for both local storage and local function as it needs to do an IO.

https://jsperf.com/localstorage2

However, another main issue you may find "Browser may not allow local storage in private mode browsing".  Browsers many not allow in normal mode also due to security concern. You can learn more about local storage security concern.

// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Keny");

// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");

hope this helps.

Comment: I think both localStorage and cookies are disallowed in private mode

Comment: by private mode do you mean incognito in chrome?

Comment: In your answer, you also did not provide any source or evidence or reasons for saying NO

Comment: I updated my answer, compared to a local function, it is slower.
You can run the test given here for both local storage and local function as it needs to do an IO.


https://jsperf.com/localstorage2

Comment: @jeetendraMandal As I said earlier, I have two options either to use random function or persist data. There will be no advantage if i make a set and store the values.
My major concern is excessive get calls to localStorage might hamper the performance. will this be the case or they'll perform same

Comment: accessing local storage to set/get value is very fast. so performance is not valid criteria to select local storage.